# Tor Browser does not have permission to access the profile... Win 10/64

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, tor-install

I've looked at the other questions regarding this message, and none of the "cures" work for me.  Not even running as administrator.

The "profile" it's complaining it can't access... what's the name of the file and where is it supposed to be located?

I installed the program in a custom location `C:\Program Files\Tor Browser`.

The program wanted to install it here: `C:\Users\Droman\OneDrive\Desktop\Tor Browser`.

I wasn't interested in installing the program on the desktop, and I really don't understand why the install program was trying to do so.

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Droman

Answer (score 4):

Usual software is installed by writing some components to a specific location like `C:\Program Files` and when it is used such software creates user-specific files in your home directory. The Tor Browser doesn't work this way.

It can run from any location (your home directory, an USB stick, etc.). Therefore the software is rather unpacked than installed.

When you start it, it creates several files in the directory where it is started. The user who starts Tor Browser needs to have write permissions to this directory. The directory `C:\Program Files` is specific and usually doesn't allow writing to it. Even the Administrator needs special permissions. So I would strongly recommend against writing to that directory.

Instead try to find another location like `C:\User\Username` or some similar directory and let Tor Browser run from there.